# Select where column in not null array

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I am trying to do :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column IN (SELECT col FROM table2 WHERE col2 = value )
```

but I want to check if the second request doesn't return a null array.

How is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide sample data with desired results?  What do you mean check for a null array, no records existing in the subquery?  What should it do if the subquery has no results?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `NOT NULL` check in the subquery to omit the null values returned.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN 
(SELECT col FROM table2 WHERE col2 = value AND col IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: This will only omit NULLL from col2, not omit NULLs from col, which is what I think he wants.